# "Where should I put the question mark (?)(,)" asked RoDaSm(?)

Tags: punctuation

"Where should I put the question mark(1.?)(,)" asked RoDaSm(2.?)

If I place the question mark at the end of the first clause (1.), I should start the second clause with a capital letter and make it a new sentence, but *Asked RoDaSm* is not sentence. so I'm left with either of the two options written below. Could someone shed some light on whether the alternatives are correct or considered acceptable usage?

1."Where should I put the question mark?" asked RoDaSm.
2."Where should I put the question mark," asked RoDaSm?

Would the same rule apply for a sentence such as: "What am I'm supposed to do with that," said RoDaSm?

Answer (score 4):

"X asked Y" is a declarative sentence. Declarative sentences do not take question marks.

"Where should I put the question mark?" is a question. Questions do take question marks.

Consequently, your second option is not an option.

Note how I just wrote:

> "Where should I put the question mark?" is a question.

That is what you should do, too.

Comment: It's worth noting that while different styles disagree about whether certain punctuation should be inside or outside quotation marks, they all agree with this answer when it comes to question marks.